# Visa to attend conference in Canada - Shall I contact the conference organisers?

Tags: conference, canada, international, visa

I have submitted an abstract to attend a forthcoming conference in July 2023. The decision on my abstract is still pending. Is it okay to contact the organizers and inquire about the status of the application since I don't know how much time the visa process will take?

Comment: In which country will you be submitting your application

Comment: India. I have to apply for research grant also, requesting the indian government for conference registration fee, travel fare etc. The conference is in second week of july

Comment: You've asked two questions, but the SE format is much better with 1. Can you delete the question you aren't interested in?

Comment: Your second question depends only on your individual details and is non really relevant for here. However your first question (whether you should contact the organisers) is still useful.

Comment: Sure. Edited the question as suggested

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is OK to contact the organisers. They may or may not give you a helpful response.

Comment: I'm not sure why this is downvoted - it answers the (trivial) question.

Answer (score 0):

[Visa process]
The processing time varies

- the visa type
- the place (country) of application
- personal circumstances

See Government of Canada's site for [approximate processing time for visa type and country of application](https://www.canada.ca/en/immigration-refugees-citizenship/services/application/check-processing-times.html).
For instance, the median for application from India might take around mid of 2 and 3 weeks, while from China is almost double at between 4 to 5 weeks.
The UK comes in unrealistically close to a year and South Africa at about 187days.

Regarding whether to request or not, a starter is

- what are the **important dates** (deadlines) for the conference.
  Most conference will give approximate dates for
- submitting abstracts/manuscripts
- acceptance: outcomes to authors
- revision, camera ready paper... (this can be single or two or three iterations)

> decision on my abstract is still pending

Is the pending decision within the published timelines or past.
If past, you may safely contact the organisers, respectfully so. If within, you might have to walk circumspectly taking into consideration the approximate visa processing times.
NB: the conference organisers are not obligated to write you visa support letter if your abstract has not been accepted.

PS: Above assumes that abstract acceptance is all that is required for the conference attendance. It assumes that abstract acceptance is not the first step (requirement) for submitting a (full) paper that must also go through review.

Comment: *Unrealistically* close to a year : Untrue, it is quite logical, immigrants in the UK have way more reasons and financial will to go to Canada than applicants in India, for ex.

Comment: @NicolasFormichella : I find it unrealistic: I even thought it's a glitch in the system. However, what I posted came from the **[Canada Gov site](https://www.canada.ca/en/immigration-refugees-citizenship/services/application/check-processing-times.html)**. I had a hunch to post the screenshot, but decided against it. The extract is ... {*Visitor visa (from outside Canada) | United Kingdom | 337 days*}

Comment: Yes, sounds about right. It is far from unrealistic. Like I said, when you're an immigrant in a *first-world* country, you are much more likely to want to visit other *first-world*. And you will have many more grounds (financial means, work ties...) to get a visa to those countries. Which makes for way more applicants, and therefore lead times are huge (from the UK, US visa is 100 days, from France it's 140 days)

Comment: Due to an edit to the question, this answer no longer answers the question.